# Make Django not lazy-load module, for development convenience

Tags: python, django

I notice that Django lazy-loads modules that are used in the project. When I first run the server in debug on my local machine, and then load a page from the site, the debugger tells me that Django just imported more than a hundred modules.

I'd like Django to import all modules when it's launched, and not wait for the first request. This will make my development more convenient, since I won't have to wait more time on each first request.

Is this possible?

Comment: One idea might be to write your own management command, inheriting from the `runserver` command, which after starting the server does *something* that triggers all the imports (i.e. hits the server with a dummy call).

Comment: I considered it, but I'd rather not do a dummy call, for fear it might have other effects. I'd prefer getting Django to load the models in a more direct way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up just adding a section like this to my manage.py, right before the `execute_from_command_line` line:

```
argv_string = ' '.join(sys.argv)
if ('gunicorn' in argv_string) or ('runserver' in argv_string):
    import all_my_stuff
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like this library: https://github.com/ojii/django-load, which is fairly simple, has a function to load a module from within Django.  If you combine that technique with a Django entry point hook (like http://eldarion.com/blog/2013/02/14/entry-point-hook-django-projects/), you should be able to explicitly load your modules at startup.  (I did not try it myself, but it looks feasible.)